# Connect4 game with 2D arrays diagonal check

Tags: java

So Im pretty new at java and i have an assignment to create a connect 4 game. I create a board 6 rows and 7 columns full of characters like this one -> '-', when the user inputs the desire column it replaces the '-' with a B or R (Red or black checker) well whatever this is just a background. Everything works except for the part that my code for checking diagonals its awfully long, i couldnt figure out a way to go through all the possible 4 sets of diagonals in which a player can win, except by doing each one in a different for loop... I know its horrible hope you can help me to do it shorter :(

this is the code for diagonal check: (lol only looking at it makes me feel sad)

```
    public class Connect4 {
          public static void main(String[] args) {

      //Create board

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    char[][] grid = new char[6][7];

    for (int i = 0; i < grid.length; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < grid[0].length; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = '-';
      }
    }

 public static void checkWinner(char[][] grid) {      
try{

  //A LOT OF FOR LOOPS FOR DIAGONAL CHECKS
    for (int i = 5; i > 1; i-- ) {
     for(int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
           if (   grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                  grid[i-1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                  grid[i-2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                  grid[i-3][j+3] == 'R') {
                  System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                  System.exit(0);
           }
           else if (  grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i-1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i-2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i-3][j+3] == 'B') {
                      System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
           }
         }
     }


     for (int i = 5; i > 1; i--) {
         for (int j = 1; j < 4; j++) {
                  if (grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i-1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i-2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i-3][j+3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
              }
             else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i-1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i-2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i-3][j+3] == 'B') {
                      System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
         }
     }
   }

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         for (int j = 4; j < 7; j++) {
             if (   grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+1][j-1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+2][j-2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+3][j-3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
         }
             else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i+1][j-1] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i+2][j-2] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i+3][j-3] == 'B') {
                      System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
         }
     }
   }

     for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
         for (int j = 6; j > 5; j--) {
             if (   grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+1][j-1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+2][j-2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+3][j-3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
                        }
             else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i+1][j-1] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i+2][j-2] == 'B' &&
                      grid[i+3][j-3] == 'B') {
                      System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
         }
        }
     }

     for (int i = 4; i < 5; i++){
         for (int j = 2; j < 3; j++){
                  if (grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i-1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i-2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i-3][j+3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
                  }
                  else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i-1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i-2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i-3][j+3] == 'B') {
                          System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                          System.exit(0);
                      }
        }
     }

     for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
         for (int j = 3; j > 0; j--) {
                  if (grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+3][j+3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
                  }
                  else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+3][j+3] == 'B') {
                          System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                          System.exit(0);
                      }
     }
   }

     for(int i =0; i < 1; i++) {
         for (int j = 0; j <1; j++) {
                  if (grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+3][j+3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
             }
                  else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+3][j+3] == 'B') {
                          System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                          System.exit(0);
                 }
         }
     }

     for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++) {
         for(int i =1 ; i < 3; i++) {
                  if (grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+3][j+3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
                  }
                  else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+3][j+3] == 'B') {
                          System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                          System.exit(0);
                      }
        }
     }

     for (int j = 3; j < 4; j++) {
     for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                  if (grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+3][j+3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
                  }
                  else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+3][j+3] == 'B') {
                          System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                          System.exit(0);
                      }
         }
     }

     for (int i = 2; i < 3; i++) {
         for (int j = 2; j > 0; j--) {
                  if (grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+3][j+3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
                  }
                  else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+3][j+3] == 'B') {
                          System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                          System.exit(0);
                     }
         }
     }

     for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
         for (int j = 2; j < 3; j++){
                  if (grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+3][j+3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
                  }
                  else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+3][j+3] == 'B') {
                          System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                          System.exit(0);
                   }
         }
     }

     for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++) {
         for (int j = 1; j < 2; j++){
                  if (grid[i][j] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+1][j+1] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+2][j+2] == 'R' &&
                      grid[i+3][j+3] == 'R') {
                      System.out.println("Player 1 Wins!");
                      System.exit(0);
                   }
                  else if (grid[i][j] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+1][j+1] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+2][j+2] == 'B' &&
                          grid[i+3][j+3] == 'B') {
                          System.out.println("Player 2 Wins!");
                          System.exit(0);
                   }
         }
     }
 }
catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException e){
    System.out.println("Exception thrown  :" + e);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of checking every possible bit on the board, play the game based on how humans play it - It's only connect 4 when someone drops in a piece that then forms a line of four tiles. So: don't check every possible tile, use the tile that just got dropped in, and only check for lines involving that tile:

- does this new tile form a horizontal? that means checking `column-3` through `column+3` to cover all possible horizontals.
- does this new tile form a vertical? that means only checking the three tiles below it.
- does this new tile form a diagonal? that means checking {`column-3`, `row-2`} through {`column+3`, `row+3`} to cover all possible diagonals. We could even check for this at the same time we're checking for horizontals, because it traverses the same `column-3` through `column+3` range.

You already know what "color" the tile has, so your checks (in fake code) would simply be of the form:

```
boolean matched = false;
int stretch = 0;
do {
  checkTile = ...;
  matched = checkedTile.color.equals(droppedTile.color);
  if (matched) {
    if (stretch == 3) playerWins()
    stretch++;
  }
} while(matched);
```

If the largest stretch of tiles you find that have the same color is 4, done. If not, no connect-4.

That said, this is a homework assignment: S.O. is here for you when you have a problem while programming, but we're not here to do your homework for you. If you get stuck, ask your fellow students or even your teacher. The internet isn't the only place to ask help, *especially* when you're taking a course.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of coding it in a if-statement, I would e.g for the \ diagonal simply start at the position of the coin and count in direction right-lower, how many of the same color are there until the color changes, or the border is reached. Same in the left-upper direction.

At the end I would simply check if the sum of both counts plus one is greater or equal 4.

Same method for the / diagonal.

Warning: Your implementation of - and | have no array-boundary checks yet. I would recommend the counting approach for them too.

P.s. And to make your code more clear, put each check in a separate methood:

```
isHorizonallWin(x,y,color,grid)
isVerticalWin(x,y,color,grid)
isLdiagonalLeftUpper2RightLowerWin(x,y,color,grid)
isLdiagonalRightUpper2leftLowerWin(x,y,color,grid)
```