# How can i check the winner in the my Connect four java code?

Tags: java

i don't understand how to find the win way in the connect four,please tell me what should i think and how  i can find the winner in connect four.How should i use the for loop to find them.How should i use method to find the winner?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Connect4{
    public static  int[][] arrayboard(){
        int [][] board = new int[6][7];
        for (int i=0;i<board.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<board[i].length;j++){
              }
            }
          return board;     
         }
    public static void printboard(int[][] board){
            int k=5;
            for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(board[i][j] + " ");
              }
             System.out.print("|"+k );
             k--;
             System.out.println();
          }
            System.out.println("--------------+");
            System.out.println("0 1 2 3 4 5 6");
       }
     public static void player1(int[][] board){
        System.out.print("player 1 type a column(0-6) or 9 to quit current game:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int column=input.nextInt();
        for (int i=5;i>=0;i--){
            if(board[i][column]==0){
               board[i][column]=1;
               break;
            }
          }
       }
     public static void player2 (int[][] board){
        System.out.print("player 2 type a column(0-6) or 9 to quit current game:");
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int column=input.nextInt();
        for (int i=5;i>=0;i--){
            if (board[i][column]==0){
               board[i][column]=2;
               break;
           }
        }
     }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int [][] board=arrayboard();
           printboard(board);
        boolean loop= true;
              int count=0;
         while(loop){
            if (count % 2 == 0) 
                player1(board);
            else player2(board);
            count++;
            printboard(board);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After one short google the following code pops up:
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/100917/connect-four-game-in-java or http://www.lazylab.org/152/java/connect-four-game-coding-puzzle-algorithm-in-java/ or [Connect4 game with 2D arrays diagonal check](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18899576/connect4-game-with-2d-arrays-diagonal-check)

So its quite easy to find.
Theres also this Scala implementation that does the same. Only then in a different language: https://github.com/Green7izard/AP-ASE/blob/master/Scala/src/Day1.scala

Basically there are 3 ways to win:

1. Horizontally (Row). Check for every board[i] to see if a player has 4 in a row, But do be aware of of the edges of the array.
2. Vertically (Column). Check for every board [currentRow][i] to see if there is a I where 4 "currentRow"s are the same.

The last option is Diagonally. This one is harder because there are also 2 direction which you should check.

This means that you cannot check the completion in one go.
But you can make a function that will check all values like:

```
public void int GetWinner()
{
   int result = 0;
   result= CheckHorizontal();
   if(result>0) return result;
   result= CheckVertical();
   if(result>0) return result;
   result= CheckDiagonalTopLeftBotRight();
   if(result>0) return result;
   result= CheckDiagonalBotLeftTopRight();
   return result;
}
```

Execute after every move and if the result is not 0 you will have a winner!
But there are nicer ways to preform this feat!